# intercept exception with raise

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I have function, which looks for special `Element` if project files:

```
def csproj_tag_finder(mod_proj_file):

    """Looking for 'BuildType' element in each module's csproj file passed in `mod_proj_file`
        ard return it's value (CLOUD, MAIN, NGUI, NONE)"""

    try:
        tree = ET.ElementTree(file=mod_proj_file)
        root = tree.getroot()


        for element in root.iterfind('.//'):
            if ('BuildType') in element.tag:
                return element.text

    except IOError as e:
#        print 'WARNING: cant find file: %s' % e
```

If no file found - it prints `'WARNING: cant find file: %s' % e`.

This function called from another one:

```
    def parser(modename, mod_proj_file):
        ...
        # module's tag's from project file in <BuildType> elements, looks like CLOUD
        mod_tag_from_csproj = csproj_tag_finder(mod_proj_file)
        if not mod_tag_from_csproj:
            print('WARNING: module %s have not <BuildType> elements in file %s!' % (modename, mod_proj_file))
        ...
```

So - when file doesn't found - `csproj_tag_finder()`return `None` type, and print `WARNING`. Second function - `parser()` find empty `mod_tag_from_csproj` variable, and also print `WARNING`. This is harmless, so I want make `csproj_tag_finder()` raise special `Exception`, so `parser()` except it and pass `==` check, instead of print text.

I tried add something like:

```
    ...
    except IOError as e:
#        print 'WARNING: cant find file: %s' % e
        raise Exception('NoFile')
```

to `csproj_tag_finder()` to catch it later in `parser()` - but it's interrupt next steps immediately.

**P.S.** Later `if not mod_tag_from_csproj:` will call another function to add new `Element`. This task can be solved with just `return 'NoFile'` and then catch with `if/else` - but it seems to me that `raise` will more correct way here. Or not?

Answer (score 1):

`raise` interrupting the next steps immediately is exactly what it's supposed to do. In fact, that's the whole point of exceptions.

But then `return` *also* interrupts the next steps immediately, because returning early is also the whole point of `return`.

If you want to save an error until later, continue doing some other work, and then raise it at the end, you have to do that explicitly. For example:

```
def spam():
    error = None
    try:
        do_some_stuff()
    except IOError as e:
        print 'WARNING: cant find file %s' % e
        error = Exception('NoFile')
    try:
        do_some_more_stuff()
    except OtherError as e:
        print 'WARNING: cant frob the glotz %s' % e
        error = Exception('NoGlotz')
    # etc.
    if error:
        raise error
```

Now, as long as there's no unexpected exception that you forgot to handle, whatever failed last will be in `error`, and it'll be raised at the end.

---

As a side note, instead of raising `Exception('NoFile')`, then using `==` to test the exception string later, you probably want to create a `NoFileException` subclass; then you don't need to test it, you can just handle it with `except NoFileException:`. And that means you can carry some other useful information (the actual exception, the filename, etc.) in your exception without it getting in the way, too. If this sounds scary to implement, it's not. It's literally a one-liner:

```
class NoFileException(Exception): pass
```